# Why didn’t the Avengers just throw the Gauntlet into the quantum realm?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

It is known from the film *Ant-Man and the Wasp* that when anything goes into the quantum realm, it almost certainly never comes back, just as Hank Pym’s wife got lost for 30+ years. Since Professor Hulk reversed Thanos’ snap, it makes no sense to keep the Gauntlet, given the risk that Thanos will successfully or inevitably grab hold of it.

Why didn’t the Avengers throw the thing in the van, and then destroy the van? The Gauntlet would go subatomic and essentially disappear out of existence. No matter what Thanos does, he would fail to complete his goal.

Comment: Someone will be able to put up a better answer than I could about this but the gist is: blah blah Stones to be returned at their right time, blah blah blah timelines to be respected, blah blah only way anyway.

Comment: @Jenayah .. haha .. and someone did.

Comment: I'm downvoting this because it comes across as a bit of a rant .... i'm sorry, but we have to have *some* trust in the characters in the movie that this was 'the only way' or the whole narrative of two movies goes down the pan.  Some hypothetical that they could have used the quantum realm, or that they were definitely winning the battle isn't really a compelling counter proposal.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of removing the final paragraph, as it was just a rant that wasn't really important to the question. I think it's a better-quality question now.

Answer (score 6):

> "Remember, you have to return the stones to the exact moment you got
>   them or you're going to open up a bunch of nasty alternative
>   realities."
>   - Banner to Cap

This is after the final battle, when the stones are about to be sent back with CA. The reason the gauntlet was not thrown in the van immediately after use was because mere moments after Banner's "snap", Thanos launched an all out attack on the Avengers (also no one had come up with the idea to use the van yet, only the Pym particles and Stark's machine were in the question at the time). An offhand comment from one of the Avengers resulted in Ant-Man's last second idea to get the stones into the van, but even then it was to return them. He calls the van a time machine, implying that they would not be thrown in the quantum realm, but rather returned to the place and time they were taken.

Answer (score 1):

> Since Professor Hulk reversed Thanos’ snap, it makes no sense to keep the Gauntlet, given the risk that Thanos will successfully or inevitably grab hold of it.

True but **destruction** of the Gauntlet wasn't the point.

The Infinity Stones are the *important* thing and it was essential that these be returned to their original points in time so as to keep the timeline intact.

Destroying the Gauntlet and the Infinity Stones (or exiling the same to the Quantum Realm) wouldn't have achieved that goal.....in fact it would have made things worse.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answers, The Avengers needed to return the stones to their rightful place to avoid catastrophic results for the timelines they created taking them. So simply destroying or losing the stones wouldn't do that.

But other factors are that after undoing the snap, there was very little time before Thanos appeared and bombarded their headquarters. They had intended to return the stones through the Quantum Realm soon, but weren't given time.

Then when the van was remembered, they were working as fast as they could in order to get the gauntlet into the quantum realm to keep it safe, but on the final approach Thanos threw is double-blade and destroyed the van.

So by the time Tony took the stones himself to snap, all of their Quantum Realm options were already off the table.